# Why does this binding display a class name?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, xaml, silverlight-4.0

What might cause the value of a Silverlight 4 DataGridTextColumn.Header to display as *System.Windows.Data.Binding* rather than the resolved bound value? It seems like a ToString is happening somewhere that displays a class name rather than the formatted value of the class.

The binding looks like this

```
Header="{Binding Path=Dummy,Source={StaticResource languagingSource},Converter={StaticResource languagingConverter},ConverterParameter=vehicleDescription}"
```

and the problem doesn't lie anywhere within the binding as identical bindings, with different ConverterParameter values, work fine for Button.Content and TextBlock.Text properties within the same XAML page.

Even creating a simple string property like this within the local data context has the same result.

```
public string DataGridHeaderDescription { get { return "Description"; } }

Header="{Binding DataGridHeaderDescription}"
```

I've even tried adding a string format

```
Header="{Binding DataGridHeaderDescription,StringFormat=\{0\}}"
```

but this has no effect either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now possible to using bindings even on elements that aren't derived from `FrameworkElement` however the property of the element being bound must be defined as a `DependencyProperty` which `Header` is not.

Since Header is simply a place marker for any content to be placed in the header you could simply do this:-

```
<DataGridTextColumn.Header>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Dummy,Source={StaticResource languagingSource},Converter={StaticResource languagingConverter},ConverterParameter=vehicleDescription}" />
</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

Comment: Thanks for this; a simpler solution than presented in the thread I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After some further searching I found this thread that answers the question and gives some suggested solutions.

[Dynamically setting the Header text of a Silverlight DataGrid Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151682/dynamically-setting-the-header-text-of-a-silverlight-datagrid-column)