# Binding DataGridHeader ContentTemplate in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

I know that its not implicitly possible to bind text to a DataGrid header via [Dynamically setting the Header text of a Silverlight DataGrid Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151682/dynamically-setting-the-header-text-of-a-silverlight-datagrid-column), but I was following some code examples online to substitute a TextBlock for the header.  However, no matter what I do the text that I've bound to won't show up.

My XML from my view:

```
<dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=UnitKey}" IsReadOnly="True">
 <dg:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
  <Style TargetType="dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
   <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=KeyListName}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
  </Style>
 </dg:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
</dg:DataGridTextColumn>
```

My C# from my View Model:

```
    public string KeyListName
    {
        get { return keyListName; }
        set
        {
            keyListName = value;
            raisePropertyChanged("KeyListName");
        }
    }
```

I can't figure out what I overlooked.. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try using a DataGridTemplateColumn instead of a DataGridTextColumn

Comment: I was using a TemplateColumn originally, but it lost its visual style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put a datacontext in your TextBlock

```
 <TextBlock DataContext="" Text="{Binding Path=KeyListName}"/>
```

**OR**

If they have the same datacontext with your UnitKey

```
<dg:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgColumnUnit" Binding="{Binding Path=UnitKey}" IsReadOnly="True">
```

The reason why its not binding because the parent which is your DataGridTextColumn has been binded already, try to debug it and take a look at your **Output window** it will prompt that **KeyListName cannot be found ....**