# Binding DataGrid column headers in Silverlight

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I've seen quite a few unanswered posts on this topic, yet I'm still inclined to believe someone on here as figured this out and is holding out on the rest of us.

I have a DataGrid that contains a mix of template columns and text columns. I just need a way of binding the headers to properties in the viewmodel so that I can use different strings for different languages.

I've seen [WPF datagrid header text binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658397/wpf-datagrid-header-text-binding) and every post linked from it. None of the methods suggested here work in Silverlight.

Does no one have any ideas?

Comment: found the answer http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2011/03/07/datagridcolumn-bindable-header-for-localization-support-in-silverlight-4/

Answer (score 1):

I've recently spent a bit of time working on this too, here is how I got it working for other peoples benefit.

First declare namespace up top so I can specify it short hand in the xaml.

```
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
```

Then I declare header styles as static resources up top to keep the datagrid xaml clean:

```
<navigation:Page.Resources>        
    <Style x:Key="NameStyle" TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedStrings.Name, Source={StaticResource Language}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DescriptionStyle" TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedStrings.Description, Source={StaticResource Language}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</navigation:Page.Resources>
```

Then in your datagrid xaml you can simply set your DataGridTextColumns Header style to your static resource header style.

```
<sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" FontSize="11" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Name}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource NameStyle}" />
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" FontSize="11" Binding="{Binding Description}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DescriptionStyle}" />
</sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
```

My original solution was from this post: [Dynamically setting the Header text of a Silverlight DataGrid Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151682/dynamically-setting-the-header-text-of-a-silverlight-datagrid-column)

Just tidied it up a bit as I had 15 column headers to set.